# Restore svn trunk of my plugin repository to the initial state?

Tags: plugin-development

I messed it up and I don't know how to fix it. I thought it would be easier if I just literally delete all the files and start over again. Is there a way to do it? I tried some tips in google to no avail. Neither 'svn cleanup' nor 'svn delete' works. :-(

Comment: Did you already commit files to the repository? If not, you can just check out the empty directory again in another location and work from there. If you don't know, tell us the name of your plugin and we can check the repository too.

Comment: It's paypal subscription button. Yah I did commit it already. I am new to using VCS so I am not really sure what's happening. The trunk misses some important directories if I view it from the browser yet they are all present if I download it from the download page. The working files are in tags/1.0.2. Thanks!

Comment: Whats your plugin svn url,  and sometimes it takes up to 15 minutes to upadte as wordpress plugin svn updates every 15 minutes

Comment: @בניית אתרים: http://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/paypal-subscription-button/

Comment: Looks like it's not possible huh?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the root directory of your SVN checkout directory, try this:

```
svn revert -R 
svn update
```

That usually will restore it to the main state.

Comment: Hi thanks! What do you mean main state? I want it to fresh like when I first check it out, is that you mean?

Comment: No, that's not what I mean. That will revert any changes you've made to your working copy. If you've actually checked in some changes, then that's that. They're checked in. You'll have to manually rollback to a previous version and then check it in again to remove them. This is a version management system; the whole point is for it to not lose changes... Once you check in, there is no going back except manually.

Comment: Thanks! reverting it somehow fixes the problem. I can now `svn arg` without a hitch! :-)